# Delphi => C#: função genérica para retornar DV de boleto de cobrança

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo, boleto

Estou com problemas em uma função de Modulo 11 personalizada (que retorna corretamente o dv de boleto de cobrança de qualquer banco) que já tinha ela em Delphi, e como estou precisando da mesma implementar em um sistema em C#.

Então tentei fazer a versão C# dela, mas ta com erro de lógica ou sintaxe, já que não tenho muita afinidade com C#.

Vale ressaltar que do ponto de vista sequencial de fluxo comparada à versão Delphi, na minha opinião, está correta.

Segue:

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Remove a primeira ocorrência da substring em uma string completa
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">String completa</param>
    /// <param name="remove">String para ser removida</param>
    /// <returns>Retorna a nova string sem os caracteres que foram retirados</returns>

    public static string RemoveFirst(this string source, string remove)
    {
        int index = source.IndexOf(remove);
        return (index < 0)
            ? source
            : source.Remove(index, remove.Length);
    }


            /// <summary>
            /// Valida o dígito verificador da linha digitável
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="Valor">Linha Digitável</param>
            /// <param name="Base"></param>
            /// <param name="Resto"></param>
            /// <returns>Retorna o dígito verificador correspondente a linha digitável avaliada</returns>

            public static string Modulo11LinhaDigitavel(string Valor, int Base = 9, bool Resto = false)
            {

                int peso = 2;
                int soma = 0;
                int contador, digito, i;
                string retorno = "";

                for (i = 1; i <= Valor.Length; i++)
                {
                    int pos = Valor[i].ToString().IndexOf("0123456789");

                    if (pos < 0)

                        RemoveFirst(Valor, Valor[i].ToString());

                }

                Valor = Valor.Substring(0, 4) + // 1 e 4
                              Valor.Substring(32, 15) + // 33 e 15
                              Valor.Substring(4, 5) +  // 5 e 5
                              Valor.Substring(10, 10) + // 11 e 10
                              Valor.Substring(21, 10); // 22 e 10

                                                   // 1 e 4                    // 6 e 39
                Valor = Valor.Substring(0, 4) + Valor.Substring(5, 39);

                for (contador = Valor.Length; contador >= 0; contador--)
                {
                    soma = soma + (Convert.ToInt32(Valor[contador]) * peso);

                    if (peso < Base)
                    {
                        peso = peso + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peso = 2;
                    }
                }

                if (Resto)
                {
                    retorno = (soma % 11).ToString();
                    return retorno;
                }
                else
                {
                    digito = 11 - (soma % 11);

                    if (digito > 9) 
                    { 

                        digito = 0;

                        retorno =  digito.ToString();

                        return retorno;
                    }
                }

                if (retorno == "0") { retorno = "1"; }

                return retorno;
            }

// Uma vez funcionado, teria que retornar 5, que é o DV da linha digitável abaixo em questão        

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Modulo11LinhaDigitavel("10490.05539 03698.700006 00091.449587 5 55490000028531"));
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

A versão Delphi pode ser vista [aqui](http://pastebin.com/hjEbPtdQ)

Comment: Mas qual é o erro? O que acontece de errado?

Comment: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: Em que linha dá isto? Mostra qual, não adainta passar o número

Comment: `int pos = Valor[i].ToString().IndexOf("0123456789");`

Comment: Jonas, existe uma biblioteca open source para geração de boletos para qualquer banco no Brasil, ela é muito utilizada e a comunidade contribui muito para que se mantenha atualizada. **Boleto.NET** - https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet Talvez você resolva utilizá-la para fazer a impressão, geração de arquivos de remessa e retorno, etc. Senão for o caso de adotar a biblioteca por completo, lá tem o [cálculo do módulo 11](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/blob/51ad9733b36e9bf72a6d0d33d685a94ee534c7ae/src/Boleto.Net/Util/Extensions.cs).

Comment: Que tal colocar uns 2 ou 3 exemplos de linhas digitáveis e os resultados esperados para a operação, quem sabe assim fique mais fácil de lhe ajudar.

Comment: Prontinho @RichardDias, Está [aqui](http://pastebin.com/cd7a2UEV) o resultado esperado é o mesmo dígito verificador geral das respectivas linhas.

Comment: @JonasSilva eu editei a resposta. Eu tinha comido bola em uma linha e por não entender bem o que um determinado comando fazia no Delphi, acabei tirando uma parte que depois eu vi o que fazia de fato. Agora está correto e simplificado. Pode ver executando no *link* que eu passei na resposta.

Comment: @bigown, agora sim! hehehe muito obrigado. Espero que sua solução ajude futuros leitores desta questão, pois como falei, a maioria dessas funções de Modulo 11 que tem na internet ou todas (exeto essa solução aí) não funcionam como deveria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra não ficar sem nenhuma resposta eu dei uma melhorada. Consertei alguns erros. Tinha coisas que a tradução do código estava completamente errada, ou tinha problemas de performance, e o estilo não era C#. Tinha coisas desnecessárias também. Pode não ser o resultado desejado, mas agora pelo menos executa sem erro e tem uma base melhor para depurar e achar se tem algo errado. Ficou assim:

```
public static string Modulo11LinhaDigitavel(string valor, int digitoBase = 9, bool resto = false) {
    var linha = new StringBuilder(valor.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < valor.Length; i++) {
        if ("0123456789".IndexOf(valor[i]) >= 0) {
            linha.Append(valor.Substring(i, 1));
        }
    }
    var linhaOrdenada = linha.ToString();
    linhaOrdenada = linhaOrdenada.Substring(0, 4) + 
                    linhaOrdenada.Substring(32, 15) + 
                    linhaOrdenada.Substring(4, 5) +  
                    linhaOrdenada.Substring(10, 10) + 
                    linhaOrdenada.Substring(21, 10); 
    linhaOrdenada = linhaOrdenada.Substring(0, 4) + linhaOrdenada.Substring(5, 39);
    var soma = 0;
    var peso = 2;
    for (var i = linhaOrdenada.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        soma += Convert.ToInt32(linhaOrdenada.Substring(i, 1)) * peso;
        if (peso < digitoBase) {
            peso++;
        } else {
            peso = 2;
        }
    }
    var retorno = "";
    if (resto) {
        retorno = (soma % 11).ToString();
    } else {
        var digito = 11 - (soma % 11);
        if (digito > 9) { 
            digito = 0;
        }
        retorno = digito.ToString();
    }
    if (retorno == "0") { return "1"; }
    return retorno;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EoJxa4). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jvAOOe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/VerificationDigit.cs).

Pegar o manual e fazer um código próprio pode dar bem menos trabalho. Esse algoritmo não é bom, poderia ser feito de forma melhor.

Comment: Vc viu aí no resultado? o DV era pra ser 5 e retorna 6. Não está errado isso não está? :-)

Comment: Deve estar, mas eu fiz o que pude com o que você mostrou. Agora só se eu pegar o manual e fazer pra você. Ou fazer um serviço de tradução de código completo. Não é o objetivo do site.

Comment: Não deu certo não :D, ta saindo resultados diferentes pra outros boletos que tem a linha nesse mesmo formato. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.