# Qual o mais rápido na construção de texto via StringBuilder Append()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio

Possuo um texto grande (1000 linhas) com formatações. De maneira resumida (não é esse texto mas irei usar um exemplo) tenho 2 maneiras de construí-lo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("oi" +
    "meu nome" +
    "é" +
    "Jonny");
```

Ou

```
    sb.append("oi");
    sb.append("meu nome");
    sb.append("é");
    sb.append("Jonny");
```

em tempo de execução e memória, qual seria o mais adequado? Ou os dois são executados na mesma velocidade?

Estou utilizando o visual studio 2017.

Comment: Creio que se houver diferença será tão minima que você nem poderá perceber! Há coisas piores para se preocupar em uma aplicação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro sem dúvida alguma porque ele na prática é o mesmo que

```
sb.append("oimeu nomeéJonny");
```

Se for com variáveis é o mesmo que:

```
sb.append(string.Concat(v1, v2, v3, v4));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BuilderPerformance.cs).

O segundo são 4 operações isoladas. portanto custa mais caro. Claro que haverá ganho em uma operação grande, mas o ganho será maior se puder evitar algumas dessas operações. Haverá ganho se puder dar um tamanho pelo menos aproximado da *string* final, mesmo que seja um pouco exagerado pode compensar bastante.

Se for fazer só 4 *appends* não compensa usar o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ele serve para uma quantidade grande de inclusões e que seja em uma laço ou mecanismo semelhante. Se for sem um laço em geral compensa mais usar um [`Concat()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), [`Join()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), [`Format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou mesmo [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101).

Para este exemplo específico, se não tiver mais nada deve fazer o mais simples, será o mais rápido também. Se for só isso seria um absurdo muito grande usar o primeiro. O segundo seria só um absurdo.

veja mais em:

- [Usando Concat para concatenar array de strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191264/101)
- [Por que devo usar a classe StringBuilder ao invés da classe String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101)
- [String e sua eficiência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16050/101)
- [Performance: string "concatenado" ou todo na mesma linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7734/101)
- [O que faz o join() ser tão superior se comparado a outras técnicas de concatenação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101)
- [Como melhorar comparação e concatenação de string C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89738/101)
- [Fazer substituição de strings com Regex é mais lento do que Replace()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138705/101)
- [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186644/101)
- [Delphi => C#: função genérica para retornar DV de boleto de cobrança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125480/101)
- [HTML dentro de um StringBuilder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191611/101)
- [Performance: string "concatenado" ou todo na mesma linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7734/101)

Não importa se está usando Visual Studio 2017, [isto nada tem a ver com o IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Comment: Então eu utilizei um exemplo bem simples mas em um sistema onde eu tenho 400 linhas para executar uma Query sql eu poderia ter mais de 100 linhas então queria saber mesmo qual utilizar para que eu não perca nenhum problema em performace

Comment: Bom, quando você quer perguntar uma coisa o ideal é perguntar aquilo que quer saber, colocar todos os detalhes. É como se estivesse programando um computador, se não coloca tudo vai ter problemas. Como não sabemos nem ao certo o que quer fazer não tem como saber qual utilizar. Por isso que é melhor entender todo o mecanismo para tomar a decisão em cada circunstância, já que cada uma é diferente da outra.

Comment: Ok especifiquei um pouco melhor, então se eu tenho um texto é muito melhor concatenar em 1 append só do que fazer 1000 appends ?

Comment: Não está especificado melhor, está a mesma coisa, só que agora tem um número que não quer dizer nada, continuo dizendo a mesma coisa.